# Make player die if they fall off the platform

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, iam making a 3d endless runner game with unity. I want the game to stop(just like when the player hits an obstacle) when my character falls of the platform. Keep in mind that when starting the game the character's ***y position is -1.4 ***

I tried this code but it didnt work:

```
 if ( transform.position.y < -1.5)
        {
            //printing game over-stopping the game
            SC_PlayerMove.instance.gameOver = true;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it worked for me when I placed it inside the update function. If you add a `Debug.Log` inside the if statement, check that it prints when the condition occurs. If it does, then it might be an issue with how you're handling game over.